# registration in openni_launch

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_launch/Tutorials/QuickStart

What is the registration?

What is the difference "rosrun image_view disparity_view image:=/camera/depth_registered

/disparity" and "rosrun image_view disparity_view image:=/camera/depth/disparity" ?

I don't find difference of them.

When we use them?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36647/registration-in-openni_launch/) by [rosmaker](https://answers.ros.org/users/2491/rosmaker/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2012-06-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am not completely sure, but from what I could understand, the registered data matches the depth information and relates to the **RGB** camera.

By taking a look at the **/camera/depth_registered/disparity**   we can see that it is slightly different from **/camera/depth/disparity**

**/camera/depth_registered/disparity** seems to be the image got from the rgb camera, showing only the part that is visible by the depth sensor. It is useful when you want to relate the RGB image and the depth points. Imagine you want to 3D scan an object. If you need to know the color of that object, you should use **/camera/depth_registered** . That is how the **/camera/depth_registered/points** might be built, as it kind of mix the information from RGB camera and depth sensor.

**/camera/depth/disparity** contains the raw depth information from the depth sensor, though.

---

Originally posted by [Joao Ferreira](https://answers.ros.org/users/13366/joao-ferreira/) with karma: 81 on 2014-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0